# Which one is the correct answer?

Tags: grammar

Which one is the correct answer?
And why?

> I couldn't have helped you if you ___ here yesterday.

a) was
b) are
c) were
d) had been

Comment: Which answer do *you* think may be correct? Why do you think the others are incorrect? Why is b) preferable to b)? I couldn't have helped you even if you had been here tomorrow.

Comment: @WeatherVane Why is b) preferable to b)?

Comment: That's what I wrote. Why are you repeating it?

Comment: @WeatherVane - I've corrected the second (b) to (d).

Answer (score 1):

**were** is the correct answer.

I believe it's called an unreal conditional clause and it requires the [subjunctive **were**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/getting-in-the-subjunctive-mood) because it's completely hypothetical. The situation won't ever happen because it's in the past (and didn't happen).

P.S. At least in spoken American English, **had been** would be totally acceptable.

Comment: Same in UK English.

Comment: To my Canadian ears, "were" is incorrect. "Had been" is the only correct answer